# What is this data structure in pygsheets?

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, pygsheets

```
# Authorize Spreadsheet Access
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file=gServiceAccAuthFile, retries=1)
# Open spreadsheet
sh = gc.open_by_key(gSheetKey)
# Open Worksheet
wks = sh.worksheet_by_title(gWorksheetName)
mydict = wks.get_values('A1','A55',returnas='cell')

print(mydict[5])

[<Cell A6 'MY CELL CONTENTS'>]
```

I'd like to find out what this data type is, and how I can use the separate values (`Cell A6` (or just `A6`) and `MY CELL CONTENTS`).

I've tried `print(mydict[5][0])`
but this just returns:
`<Cell A6 'MY CELL CONTENTS'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the `pygsheets` documentation: https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

And the relevant sections:

- `Worksheet.get_values()` : https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet.html#pygsheets.Worksheet.get_values
- `Cell` : https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cell.html#pygsheets.Cell.value

---

Looks like your selection gets a list of lists of `Cell` objects, so it would make more sense to call it `my_list`.

You can access the value with `Cell.value`. In this case `my_list[6][0].value`.

If you want to specifically access the value of A6, there's no need to select the entire range. You can use `Worksheet.get_value`.

```
print(wks.get_value('A6'))
```

Or if you do actually need the cell,

```
a6 = wks.cell('A6')
print(a6.value)
```

Comment: Thanks, point taken about making this a list instead. I do need to access both the range and the value. Is there any way to do something like `my_list[6].range`?

Comment: your solution returned `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'value'`

Comment: Hmm, looks like you're actually getting a list of lists. I'll edit my answer

Comment: I appreciate that this is a separate question, but what I'd actually like to do, is select cell by contents, and apply formatting (change cell background). But I get the same type of data returned when I use the find operator.